# i am failing to register a user in my school management project i keep getting a bad request

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views, react-fullstack

I don't know if something is wrong with my code

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def sign_up(request):

user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
if user_serializer.is_valid():
    user = user_serializer.save()
else:
    return Response({'message':'invalid'}, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)

userType = request.data.get('user_type')

if userType == 'student':
    student_serializer = StudentSerializer(data=request.data)
    if student_serializer.is_valid():
        student = student_serializer.save()
        user_student_relation = UserStudentRelation.objects.create(user=user, student=student)

        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        access_token = str(refresh.access_token)
        refresh_token = str(refresh)
```

return Response({
'access_token': access_token,
'refresh_token': refresh_token,
}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
else:
user.delete()  # Rollback user creation if student creation fails
return Response(student_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

i expected a student to be created through the user model and get linked with the student model but i keep getting a bad request

Comment: Can you share the json you are sending in the body of your post-request?

Comment: method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({name, password, grade, contact, image, studentId, 
               user_type}),